# Integer user input in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, input

I am writing a GUI application in Qt.

I need to get from the user a set of integers which will be loaded in an array. What might be the go to way to do this visually. This may seem easy but I don't have much experience in GUI applications. I'm thinking of using a lineEdit but that takes text as input and I'm not sure how to handle the input in that case.

For future reference if somebody has a similar question this is how I did it using line edit:

```
//Read input as string from line edit
QString input_text = ui->lineEdit->text();

if(input_text.isEmpty())
    return;

//Check for letters or symbols
for (int i = 0; i < input_text.length(); i++)
    if(input_text.at(i).isLetter() || input_text.at(i).isSymbol() || input_text.at(i).isPunct())
        return;

//Split input in parts around 'space'
QStringList input_list = input_text.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

//Copy those parts to array as integers
for (int i = 0; i < input_list.length() && i < current_array_size; i++)
    array.replace(i, input_list.at(i).toInt() );
```

Comment: hey, welcome to SO first of all. You said you are writing something, so maybe you could start with post your code together with the problem your facing. Please consider to check [example]

Comment: `QLineEdit::text` gives you `QString`. Use [`QString::toInt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) to get the presumably entered integer number, or react accordingly, if the text does not represent an integer number.

Comment: @scopchanov if the input looks something like this: “4 5 7 1” or “5, 6, 7” can I get each number separately? The idea is that the user will write all inputs once and hit a button. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dboy lol thanks but I don’t see how that could help since I don’t have a bug or something. I’m asking about a problem that I’m not sure how to approach so it’s not implemented jet. Hope this clarifies that and thanks for the help

Comment: Of course you can break the input down to individual numbers. `QString` offers a bunch of neat methods to help you with that. It depends on the particular use case, which one(s) should be used and how. That is exactly what the _mre_ is for. But when you say, I do not know how to approach that at all, then you do not need to post a question on this site, but to read a book or tutorial or something. Check out the [description of the qt tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info) for some very useful resources on this topic.

Comment: Much better! There is still no question asked, but at least it much more clear what you try to achieve. Suggestion: instead of manually parsing the string, try to split it first and then use the boolean flag of `QString::toInt` to check if the substring can be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a good start point is something like a list view or table view or list widget:

- https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistview.html
- https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtableview.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html

Couple this with an QLineEdit as an entry mechanism.

User types in a number - hits enter (link that signal to validate and enter the number into which even list you want).

Then later when you want to get at the numbers use the qlistview (or whatever) to populate the vector....or just leave the data in the Qlistview and dont use a vector (depending what you want to do)....

Comment: @scopchanov  I maybe did not understand that the OP only wanted to use a QLineEdit, my bad if so. As to "why on earth?" - Having a list and a separate entry "box" is a fairly standard pattern in GUIs, and you see it all over the place, because its very intuitive. Course, you don't *have* to do it that way. But, for example you may have a very long list but you always want the entry "field" at the top where it obvious that its a data entry location. There are other patterns - not saying this is 100% the only way, its a suggestive answer. But

Comment: I understand what you say and _why on earth_ was indeed not the best way to express my point of view. Sorry about that! However, I really wouldn't bother with UI aspects, regardless of the pattern used (direct data manipulation or through an entry form), when the OP obviously struggles with much simpler things.

Comment: @scopchanov no worries. Fair points, I probably mis-understood the question - it seems to have been updated quite a lot so, I will re-think the "answer" or delete it

Comment: Well, it is hard to answer, when there is no question in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

You also try this :

```
int INT_NUM ; 
QString STRING_NUM = ui->Line_Edit->text();
INT_NUM = STRING_NUM.toInt();
```